# Portable support for large files

Tags: c++, c, large-files

I looked at

- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18293310/how-can-i-portably-turn-on-large-file-support)
- [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026896/get-large-file-size-in-c)
- [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965725/large-file-support-in-c)

and I still don't know how to get to know size of file larger than 4 gb in a portable way.

Notably, incorporating some of the answers failed compiling for Cygwin, while the others failed for Linux.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Turns out there are quite a few functions defined by various standards:

1. #### `fseek`/`ftell`

   It's defined by ANSI standard library. It's available virtually everywhere. It is guaranteed to work with 32-bit integers only, but it isn't required to (meaning you might get support for large files out of the box).
2. #### `fseeko`/`ftello`

   This is defined by POSIX standard. On many platforms, depending on value of `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS` it will cause `off_t` to be defined as `off64_t` and `fseeko` as `fseeko64` for `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`.
3. #### `fseeko64`/`ftello64`

   This is the 64-bit equivalent of `fseeko` and `ftello`. I couldn't find information on this in any standard.

   **Cygwin inconsistency**

   While it conforms to POSIX, I can't compile the `fseeko` no matter what I define under Cygwin, unless I use `--std=gnu++11` which is obviously nonsense, since it's part of POSIX rather than a GNU extension. So what gives? According to [this discussion](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2007-10/msg00594.html):

   > 64 bit file access is the natural
   >   file access type for Cygwin.  off_t is 8 bytes.  There are no foo64
   >   functions for that reason.  Just use fopen and friends and you get 64
   >   bit file access for free.

   This means `#ifdef` for cygwin on POSIX platforms.
4. #### `_fseeki64` / `_ftelli64`

   These are defined by Microsoft Visual C++ and are exclusively used with their compiler. Obviously it doesn't support anything else from the list above (other than `fseek`), so you're going to need `#ifdef`s.

   **EDIT**: I actually advise against using them and [I'm not the only one who thinks that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034227/on-windows-fseeki64-does-not-seek-to-seek-end-correctly-for-large-files). I experienced literally following:

   1. `wfopen` a file in binary mode
   2. `fwrite` 10 bytes worth to it
   3. `_ftelli64` the position
   4. It returns 12 rather than 10 bytes

   Looks like this is horribly broken.
5. #### `lseek` and `lseek64`

   Defined by POSIX, these are to be used with integer file descriptors opened with `open()` from `unistd.h` rather than `FILE*` structs. These are not compatible with Windows. Again, they use `off_t` data type.
6. #### `_lseek`, `_lseeki64`

   This is Windows equivalent of `lseek`/`lseek64`. Curiously, `_lseeki64` doesn't use `off_t` and uses `__int64` instead, so you *know* it'll work with big files. Neat.
7. #### `fsetpos`/`fgetpos`

   While these are actually pretty portable, they're almost unusable, since they operate on opaque structures rather than integer offsets, meaning you can add or subtract them, or even navigate to certain position in file obtained by any means other than through `fgetpos`.

## Conclusion

So to make your program portable, depending on the platform, you should use:

- `fseeko` (POSIX) + define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` on POSIX
- `fseek` for Cygwin and for default implementation
- `_lseeki64` for Windows - or, if you manage to work your way around it - `_fseeki64`.

An example that uses `_ftelli64`:

```
int64_t portable_ftell(FILE *a)
{
#ifdef __CYGWIN__
    return ftell(a);
#elif defined (_WIN32)
    return _ftelli64(a);
#else
    return ftello(a);
#endif
}
```

In reality, instead of checking `#ifdef`s which always looked fragile to me, you could check if the functions compile using your build systems, and define your own constants such as `HAVE_FTELLO64` accordingly.

---

Note that if you indeed decide to use `lseek`/`_lseeki64` family and numeric file descriptors rather than the `FILE*` structures, you should be aware of following differences between `open`/`fopen`:

- `open` doesn't use buffering, `fopen` does. Less buffering means worse performance.
- `open` can't perform newline conversions for text files, `fopen` can.

  More details in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658476/c-fopen-vs-open).

---

References:

- http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/funcref.htm#stdio
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fseek.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/lseek.html
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75yw9bf3.aspx
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetpos/
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgetpos.html

Comment: Can you show me where you got the idea that defining `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` will change the behaviour of `fseeko`? Because as far as I'm aware, `fseeko` is already compiled, and the preprocessor can't change things that are already compiled... Also, you can't just go changing things like `CHAR_BIT` to get larger characters, and `INT_MAX` to get larger integer ranges... This logic seems silly to me! Nonetheless, I won't refute if it's actually backed up... but it doesn't seem Unixy at all!

Comment: @autistic More than two years later I stumbled upon your comment just after reading this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseeko.3.html. Clearly on Linux it "may" change the behavior.

Comment: @ConstantinoGrana TLDR the erroneous "define `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` on POSIX" [probably does nothing because that macro isn't used in POSIX... see?](https://www.google.com/search?q=_FILE_OFFSET_BITS%20site%3Aopengroup.org) Stop confusing Linux (man7.org) with POSIX (OpenGroup.org).

Comment: Something like [this page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) would be good to cite for `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS`... but alas, I see nothing like that.